# SaaS CMS API possible and/or useful?

Tags: json, content-management-system, saas

Everything is increasingly distributed. Outsource your authentication with Facebook or OpenID, comments with Disqus, file uploading with filepicker.io and storage with AWS. Perhaps in the future websites will merely be interfaces that link all these services together in a meaningful way to the user. Another part of a website that might be outsourced is the content. Imagine retrieving JSON with page content, menu structures and lists of blog posts. The content would be edited on a different website than your own.

A problem a CMS like this might face is the automatic creation of pages. Requiring clients to install a htaccess file could be an option. Maybe clients only want to allow automatic loading of pages on specific subredectories like domain.com/blog. Probably the routing should be left entirely to the client, and the API could be invoked on their `content-page.php`

I think it should be very minimal and not enforce use of certain template engines upon clients. It should just load the HTML of the content.

I'm not sure if this would be useful, considering that you might want your CMS to also handle routing to content pages, and I don't think that could be done through an API but please correct me if you see a way.

My question is: would you use something like this? Do you foresee any problems that I'm not seeing? Any suggestions?

To illustrate more clearly what I mean, here's an example `content-page.php` of a client:

```
$cms = new SaaSCMS($apiKey);
$content = $cms->getContent($_GET['page']);

if ($content)
{
    // Display content
}
else
{
    // 404
}
```

Comment: Google "Headless CMS"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it reminds very nicely of [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), which achieves most of the goals you stated above